# how to set cookies activetor button php html

Tags: html

Hello guys my friend using a trick his upload cookies on his side sometime visitor click on log out button then cookies
not work his create a cookies activator please anyone tell me how its done this

i Just trying to say like this 
set cookies(my target side like example.com  )
how to log in on anyone using my username password  using my HTML page
without knowing my account detail ....

Comment: Are you trying to make a HTML button that'll set a php cookie?

Comment: I would love to help but I can't understand what you are trying to ask?

Answer (score 0):

So, first of all you need to make a page that'll set a cookie. For example consider this file named `setCookie.php`:

```
<?php
setcookie("user", "Alex Porter", time()+3600);
```

Now in your regular page HTML button:

```
<button id="cookieSetter">Set Cookie</button>
```

Now using jQuery send an AJAX request to `setCookie.php` file:

```
$('#cookieSetter').click(function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   $.ajax({
     type: "GET",
     url: "setCookie.php.php"
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
            <?php
            // you should start the session before any html
             session_start();  
            // Creating some session variables like this 
            $_SESSION['pseudo'] = 'pseudo';
            $_SESSION['password'] = 'password';
            setcookie('pseudo', 'whatever', time() + 365*24*3600, null, null, false, true); // Setting up a cookie
            setcookie('location', 'Russia', time() + 365*24*3600, null, null, false, true); // Just another one...
            // And only after that you cant write html code. 
            ?> 
            <!DOCTYPE html>
            <html>
            <head>        
            <title>Your page Title</title>
            </head>
            <body> 
            <p>
            Hello <?php echo $_SESSION['pseudo']; ?> !<br />
            You are in (login.php). 
            </p>    
            <p>
            Hey  ! I remember you !<br />
            Your name is  <?php echo $_COOKIE['pseudo']; ?> and you are located in  <?php echo $_COOKIE['location']; ?> is that true?
            </p>
            <p>
            <a href="logout.php">Log out</a><br />        
            </p> 
            </body>
            </html>
```